# 'Implicit use of 'self' in closure; use 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit' when trying to switch view controllers using authentication

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, viewcontroller

I am currently learning Swift 5 in Xcode 11.4. I am attempting to build a code that when a button is pressed, it uses face-id to authenticate a user. Once the user is authenticated, it switches to a different view controller.

Currently the face-id works, but after that the app crashes. I receive this error on the present line:

> Implicit use of 'self' in closure; use 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "blue_vc") as! blueViewController
    let context:LAContext = LAContext()
    if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: nil){
        context.evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: "message") { (good, error) in
            if good {
                print("good")
                present(vc,animated: true)
            } else {
                print("error")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: Did you read the error message? It's pretty clear and contains even the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Add `self` to precisely refer to the existing view controller from inside of a the closure like so :

```
context.evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: "message") { (good, error) in
  if good {
    print("good")
    self.present(vc, animated: true)
  }
  else {
    print("error")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because evaluatePolicy completionhandler is an escaping closure that execute after function return you need to provide self to make explicit capture.

```
context.evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: "message") { (success, error) in
    guard success else { return }
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "blue_vc") as! blueViewController
    self.present(vc,animated: true) 
}
```